# CORS preflight-request header not altered on some browsers when using Preact

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cors, fetch-api, preact

I am developing a Preact project that needs to communicate with a Node.js server hosted on AWS, using the Loopback framework. To include the header api-target:rest in the requests sent to the server, I specified it in the fetchOptions. However, it seems that the header is not included in the request headers of the preflight request, which leads to CORS errors from the server.

The CORS error is:

`Access to fetch at 'https://nightli-staging-server.link/public-guest-lists/1' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Here is my code:

```
const fetchOptions: RequestInit = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'api-target',
    'api-target': 'rest',
  },
  mode: 'cors',
};

const fetchClubEventItems = async (): Promise<ClubEventItem[]> => {
  return fetch(BASE_URL + '/public-guest-lists/' + props.clubId, fetchOptions)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log('Response Headers:', res.headers);
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((result) => result);
};
```

On the server side, I am using the cors middleware with the following options:

```
  const corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true,
    exposedHeaders: ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'],
  };
  expressApp.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

When I tried my code on Chrome and Edge, two preflight requests were sent in relation to one GET-request, and the updated header api-target:rest was present in the headers of the first preflight request but not in the second. However, when I tried it on Brave, the updated header was present in both preflight requests. I suspect this may be related to the security measures of the browsers.

As a sanity check, I have forced the browsers to include api-target:rest through the use of extensions such as ModHeader, and it works perfectly without any CORS errors. I take this as an indication that the fault must be on the client-side not including the aforementioned header.

Here are screenshots of the network logs when trying the code on first Chrome and then Brave:

[Browser: Chrome
First pre-flight request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi87v.png)

[Browser: Chrome
Second pre-flight request (does not contain api-target header)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAqXQ.png)

[Browser: Brave
Second pre-flight request (contains api-target header)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcUVP.png)

My questions are:

- What could be causing the header to not be included in the preflight request?
- How can I resolve the CORS errors?
- Also, if I am not misinterpreting the network log, why are there two preflight requests?

Answer (score 1):

> What could be causing the header to not be included in the preflight request?

Regardless of the client library you use, you cannot alter preflight requests. It's the browser's job to issue those requests, not yours. See [Preflighted requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests) in the MDN Web Docs on the topic of CORS.

Besides, `Access-Control-Request-Headers` happens to be a so-called [forbidden request-header name](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-request-header). Attempts to include such a header in a request are silently ignored by browsers.

> How can I resolve the CORS errors?

One reason why preflight fails is that the preflight response has status `404`, which is not an [*ok status*](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ok-status), i.e. a status code in the 2xx range:

[image: screenshot]

An ok status is a necessary condition for preflight to succeed. See step 7 in [the CORS-preflight-fetch algorithm](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-fetch-0).

> why are there two preflight requests?

In all likelihood, your client is issuing multiple (preflighted) requests.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have a follow-up question:

Based on your previous response, should I not attempt to add the "api-target:rest" header to the preflight request, given that it is generated by the browser? It appears that forcing the header onto the preflight request using the ModHeader extension for Chrome generates a 2xx response instead of a 404 response.

Could you suggest any alternative approaches for obtaining a 2xx response on the preflight request? I would greatly appreciate any advice you can provide.

Thank you again.

Comment: _should I not attempt to add the "api-target:rest" header to the preflight request [...] ?_ No. Browsers will list `api-target` in the preflight request's `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header without any help. As for the reason you're getting a 404 response, it's impossible to answer given the lack of information regarding your server-side code.

Comment: @AdrianRoyo Don't hesitate to accept this answer if it solved your problem. It's a good way to mark your question as resolved.